# Constraining a neural network's output to be within an arbitrary range

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, constraints, custom-training

I have a custom neural network that I am training on data and seek to constrain the network's output values to always be between two arbitrary constants: `[lower_bound,upper_bound]`. Are there any best practices for encoding this constraint in a loss function?

Below I have written a minimal working example whereby I construct and train a neural network on generated data. Additionally, I place the arbitrary constraint that the output should be between `[lower_bound,upper_bound] = [-0.5,0.75]` in the loss function being optimized. But I attempt it using a relatively crude method of finding all instances where predicted values exceed the bounds, and then simply making the loss function for these terms a large value (and otherwise zero if the predicted value is within the given bounds):

```
lower_bound = -0.5 #a guessed a priori lower bound on the output
upper_bound = 0.75 #a guessed a priori upper bound on the output
cond_v1_1 = tf.greater(self.v1_pred[:,0], upper_bound*tf.ones(tf.shape(self.v1_pred[:,0])))
cond_v1_2 = tf.greater(-1.0*self.v1_pred[:,0], lower_bound*tf.ones(tf.shape(self.v1_pred[:,0])))
self.red_v1 = tf.where(cond_v1_1, 100000.0*tf.ones(tf.shape(self.v1_pred[:,0])), 0.0*tf.zeros(tf.shape(self.v1_pred[:,0]))) 
self.red_v1 = tf.where(cond_v1_2, 100000.0*tf.ones(tf.shape(self.v1_pred[:,0])), self.red_v1) 
self.loss_cond = tf.reduce_sum(1.0*tf.square(self.red_v1))
```

But are there any methods or loss functions to better encode this constraint when training the neural network? Perhaps a smoother loss function easier for the optimizers to handle and/or revisions to my code itself? Any comments and further thoughts on best practices for penalizing/training the neural network in the code below given a bound on outputs would be greatly appreciated.

---

```
import numpy as np 
import tensorflow as tf

end_it = 1000 #number of iterations
frac_train = 1.0 #randomly sampled fraction of data to create training set
frac_sample_train = 0.01 #randomly sampled fraction of data from training set to train in batches
layers = [2, 20, 20, 20, 1]

#Generate training data
len_data = 10000
x_x = np.array([np.linspace(0.,1.,len_data)])
x_y = np.array([np.linspace(0.,1.,len_data)]) 
y_true = np.array([np.linspace(-0.2,0.2,len_data)])

N_train = int(frac_train*len_data)
idx = np.random.choice(len_data, N_train, replace=False)

x_train = x_x.T[idx,:]
y_train = x_y.T[idx,:] 
v1_train = y_true.T[idx,:] 

sample_batch_size = int(frac_sample_train*N_train)

np.random.seed(1234)
tf.set_random_seed(1234)
import logging
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)

class NeuralNet:
    def __init__(self, x, y, v1, layers):
        X = np.concatenate([x, y], 1)  
        self.lb = X.min(0)
        self.ub = X.max(0)
        self.X = X
        self.x = X[:,0:1]
        self.y = X[:,1:2] 
        self.v1 = v1 
        self.layers = layers 
        self.weights_v1, self.biases_v1 = self.initialize_NN(layers) 
        self.sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=False,
                                                     log_device_placement=False)) 
        self.x_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.x.shape[1]])
        self.y_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.y.shape[1]]) 
        self.v1_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.v1.shape[1]])  
        self.v1_pred = self.net(self.x_tf, self.y_tf) 
        lower_bound = -0.5 #a guessed a priori lower bound on the output
        upper_bound = 0.75 #a guessed a priori upper bound on the output
        cond_v1_1 = tf.greater(self.v1_pred[:,0], upper_bound*tf.ones(tf.shape(self.v1_pred[:,0])))
        cond_v1_2 = tf.greater(-1.0*self.v1_pred[:,0], lower_bound*tf.ones(tf.shape(self.v1_pred[:,0])))
        self.red_v1 = tf.where(cond_v1_1, 100000.0*tf.ones(tf.shape(self.v1_pred[:,0])), 0.0*tf.zeros(tf.shape(self.v1_pred[:,0]))) 
        self.red_v1 = tf.where(cond_v1_2, 100000.0*tf.ones(tf.shape(self.v1_pred[:,0])), self.red_v1) 
        self.loss_cond = tf.reduce_sum(1.0*tf.square(self.red_v1))
        self.loss_data = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.v1_tf - self.v1_pred)) 
        self.loss = self.loss_cond + self.loss_data
        self.optimizer = tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface(self.loss,
                                                                var_list=self.weights_v1+self.biases_v1,
                                                                method = 'L-BFGS-B',
                                                                options = {'maxiter': 50,
                                                                           'maxfun': 50000,
                                                                           'maxcor': 50,
                                                                           'maxls': 50,
                                                                           'ftol' : 1.0 * np.finfo(float).eps})
        self.optimizer_Adam = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
        self.train_op_Adam_v1 = self.optimizer_Adam.minimize(self.loss, var_list=self.weights_v1+self.biases_v1) 
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()  
        self.sess.run(init)
    def initialize_NN(self, layers):
        weights = []
        biases = []
        num_layers = len(layers)
        for l in range(0,num_layers-1):
            W = self.xavier_init(size=[layers[l], layers[l+1]])
            b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,layers[l+1]], dtype=tf.float32), dtype=tf.float32)
            weights.append(W)
            biases.append(b) 
        return weights, biases
    def xavier_init(self, size):
        in_dim = size[0]
        out_dim = size[1]
        xavier_stddev = np.sqrt(2/(in_dim + out_dim)) 
        return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([in_dim, out_dim], stddev=xavier_stddev), dtype=tf.float32)
    def neural_net(self, X, weights, biases):
        num_layers = len(weights) + 1
        H = 2.0*(X - self.lb)/(self.ub - self.lb) - 1.0
        for l in range(0,num_layers-2):
            W = weights[l]
            b = biases[l]
            H = tf.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(H, W), b))
        W = weights[-1]
        b = biases[-1]
        Y = tf.add(tf.matmul(H, W), b) 
        return Y
    def net(self, x, y): 
        v1_out = self.neural_net(tf.concat([x,y], 1), self.weights_v1, self.biases_v1)
        v1 = v1_out[:,0:1]
        return v1
    def callback(self, loss):
        global Nfeval
        print(str(Nfeval)+' - Loss in loop: %.3e' % (loss))
        Nfeval += 1
    def fetch_minibatch(self, x_in, y_in, v1_in, N_train_sample):  
        idx_batch = np.random.choice(len(x_in), N_train_sample, replace=False)
        x_batch = x_in[idx_batch,:]
        y_batch = y_in[idx_batch,:] 
        v1_batch = v1_in[idx_batch,:] 
        return x_batch, y_batch, v1_batch
    def train(self, end_it):
        it = 0
        while it < end_it: 
            x_res_batch, y_res_batch, v1_res_batch = self.fetch_minibatch(self.x, self.y, self.v1, sample_batch_size) # Fetch residual mini-batch
            tf_dict = {self.x_tf: x_res_batch, self.y_tf: y_res_batch,
                       self.v1_tf: v1_res_batch}
            self.sess.run(self.train_op_Adam_v1, tf_dict)
            self.optimizer.minimize(self.sess,
                                    feed_dict = tf_dict,
                                    fetches = [self.loss],
                                    loss_callback = self.callback) 
            it = it + 1
    def predict(self, x_star, y_star): 
        tf_dict = {self.x_tf: x_star, self.y_tf: y_star}
        v1_star = self.sess.run(self.v1_pred, tf_dict)  
        return v1_star

model = NeuralNet(x_train, y_train, v1_train, layers)
 
Nfeval = 1
model.train(end_it)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way (IMHO) to do such a thing is to enforce it via the output activation function. We can use a `tf.nn.sigmoid` as a basis, which is bounded between [0, 1], and slightly shift and scale it.

```
def bounded_output(x, lower, upper):
    scale = upper - lower
    return scale * tf.nn.sigmoid(x) + lower
```

In your case, call it with `lower=-0.5` and `upper=0.75`. This will shift the sigmoid so that the lowest output is -0.5, and the range is `0.75 + 0.5 = 1.25`, which puts the upper limit at 0.75. Adding this as an output activation at the final layer of your net means outputs *cannot* fall outside the range.

One problem: This can lead to bad gradients because the function saturates as it approaches the limits. So if your network is producing outputs close to those limits, gradients will be small and learning can be slow.

Comment: I've been testing this approach and mostly like it. But is there a rule of thumb to handle the one problem? For example, if the lowest output I truly want is -0.5 and highest output is 0.75, should I add some smaller value, i.e.`-/+ buffer`, to the range such that gradients will not be exceedingly small near -0.5 and 0.75 during training? Is there a rule of thumb for selecting such a buffer value?

Comment: Good point. There is an old paper by Yann LeCun et al. ([here](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf)) which discusses this issue among others. Check sections 4.4 and 4.5. In brief, the authors propose choosing the output activation such that the target values are at the points of the _maximum second derivative_ of the activation function.

Comment: Also it makes the output biased toward scale + lower and lower, I wouldn't recommend it